# I really need help on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I kinda deleted a line on my .htacess

and now I can't open the support.sitename.com

This is my support folder, 
**public_html/support**

but how can I redirect that to **support.sitename.com**

I wrote this one,

```
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != support.sitename.com$
```

I'm pretty sure that wasn't the code I deleted. 
But it's closer than that. I'm in big trouble, please help >.<

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|gif|json|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHPMailer$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/adarna.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bh6750.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/contact-us.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/dr-holmes.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/email.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/jo-rubio.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/npk-medical.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/oraderm.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/outsource-to-philippines.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/rw-chinese.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/rw-manila.html$
>> area of code i deleted
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remove #. See what's going

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [webmasters.se]

Comment: Why was this question **`Closed`**, instead of being migrated to [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

```
# it could be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^support\.sitename\.com$
# or this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?support\.sitename\.com$

# or even this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support\.sitename\.com$
# or this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?support\.sitename\.com$
```

Depends what do you want to do with your code and where the filenames that are on your code located, in which you didn't mentioned.

To redirect */support* or */support/* into *support.sitename.com* you've better use these condition and rule on your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?support\.sitename\.com$
RewriteRule ^support/?$ http://support.sitename.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Comment: tried but the www.sitename.com isn't working. :(

Comment: did you leave the `$1` intact.

Comment: yes, why. i copy pasted the code you gave and just changed the sitename to my site

Answer (score 0):

I found this about: [**redirect support.example.com to example.com/support:**](http://devsforrest.com/4/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-a-folder)

A few different examples

```
#Turns the rewrite engine on.
RewriteEngine on

#Fix missing trailing slash character on folders.
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R,L]

#www.domain.com and domain.com will map to the folder {root}/folder1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*) folder1/$1 [NC,L,NS]

#www.otherdomain.com and otherdomain.com will map to the folder {root}/folder2/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)?otherdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/
RewriteRule ^(.*) folder2/$1 [NC,L,NS]

#subdomain.domain.com will map to the folder {root}/folder3/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:subdomain.domain.com)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3/
RewriteRule ^(.*) folder3/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```